# pdflatex and \hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation

Here is a fairly short latex file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\newcommand{\calG}{\mathcal{G}}
\newcommand{\calP}{\mathcal{P}}
\hyphenation{lem-ma none-the-less un-pa-ram-e-ter-ized}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Projection to holes is coarsely Lipschitz}
The following lemma is used repeatedly throughout the paper.
\begin{itemize}
\item
for any hole $X$ for $\calG$, the projection $\pi_X(\calP)$ is an
$A$--unparameterized quasi-geodesic and
\item
foobar.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

When I use `pdflatex` (pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.11-2.2 (TeX Live 2010/Fink)) 
I get a pair of overfull hbox errors.  If I replace `lemma` in the body by `lem\-ma` and replace `unparameterized` by `unparame\-terized` then the warnings go away.  Suggestions?

Comment: Works for me, so you'll have to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Are you using `babel` and multiple languages?

Comment: Please post a separate second question for the second question.

Comment: With regard to @egreg's comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37934/specifying-multiple-hyphenation-exception-lists-for-multi-lingual-documents

Comment: Lockstep - Ok, I'll try to do that. Egreg - English only.  Stefan - I'll split off the question.

Comment: @lockstep - Done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `\righthyphenmin` to 2, because `amsart` uses the value 3. Then lemma will be hyphenated. And words including a dash are not hyphenated. Insert a \hskip0pt. See example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\newcommand{\calG}{\mathcal{G}}
\newcommand{\calP}{\mathcal{P}}
\righthyphenmin=2
\begin{document}
\subsection{Projection to holes is coarsely Lipschitz}
The following lemma is used repeatedly throughout the paper.
\begin{itemize}
\item
for any hole $X$ for $\calG$, the projection $\pi_X(\calP)$ is an
$A$--\hskip0pt{}unparameterized quasi-geodesic and
\item
foobar.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a fine example of why minimal working examples are important.

Comment: @Herbert - I've expanded the example.  Perhaps there are two different issues here?

Comment: @Sam Nead: see my edited answer

Comment: @Herbert - Ah. I see! Thank you very much for your answers.  So, in short, the line starting `\hyphenation` is totally irrelevant.  LaTeX knows how to hyphenate these words, but there are other rules that are overriding the hyphenations (number of letter and dashes). ... So, if I have to cure each problem individually then it seems cleaner to just insert `\-` in the appropriate places (after fixing all other typesetting issues).  Does that sound right?

Comment: yes, except of `righthyphenmin`. That is easier than lem\-ma ...

Comment: ...except egreg below warns against resetting global parameters to fix a local problem.  I guess worrying about hyphens before the very very end is the biggest mistake I am making.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: There will be _no_ problems with `righthyphenmin=2`! It is more a kind of esthetic if you like it or not. In german we always use the value 2

Answer (score 6):

TeX won't hyphenate words without leaving at least `\lefthyphenmin` letters before the hyphen and `\righthyphenmin` letters after it. These two parameters are set on a per language basis; for English, the typographic traditions require

```
\lefthyphenmin=2
\righthyphenmin=3
```

so it's immaterial if you say

```
\hyphenation{lem-ma}
```

in the document's preamble: the hyphenation point will not be considered anyway. It's interesting to know that, setting `\righthyphenmin=2`, the command

```
\showhyphens{lemma}
```

shows `lem-ma` on the terminal.

While globally setting `\righthyphenmin=2` will solve the particular problem, I wouldn't recommend it, since it may add many improper hyphenation points in the rest of the document.

A "local" solution, that is, inputting `lem\-ma` at that spot is, in my opinion, the way to go: an explicit discretionary hyphen overrides the "minimum hyphenation rules" for that word.

Words containing an explicit or discretionary hyphen (`-` or `\-`) are possibly split *only* at the explicit hyphens: you can solve the problem with `$A$-unparameterized` by inserting `\hspace{0pt}`:

```
$A$-\hspace{0pt}unparameterized
```

or, maybe,

```
$A$\mbox{-}\hspace{0pt}unparameterized
```

so that TeX won't break after the explicit hyphen. Leave all these adjustments for the *final* stage of production, when you're sure that the text and the page parameters are in definitive form.

Comment: I think there may be more than one issue here.  I've expanded the example to try and show this.