# smarter hyphenation for narrow columns?

Tags: line-breaking, typography, hyphenation

I know how to turn off hyphenation via `\nohyphens{.....}` (from [hyphenat](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyphenat)).  But what I'd really like would be to hyphenate smartly.  What I mean by this should hopefully be made clear by the following example.

On the left is a piece of text from a column in a table, rendered with the `\nohyphens{...}` command.  This leaves a lot of open white space.  On the right is the same text typeset by vanilla XeLaTeX.  As you can see, it *still* leaves a big white space in the middle of the text, and it also introduces the rather strange hyphenation, "or-phaning", instead of, for example, the more natural "cor-rections".
[image: No hyphenation at all]  [image: Default behavior]

Here is a smarter version that is made by me introducing "cor-rections" into the source code:

[image: some by hand tweaking]

To my eye at least, this seems much better than either of the versions above.

So the basic question is: Could I get LaTeX to do this for me automatically, for example by specifying the longest acceptable inter-word whitespace?

*PS*. Another more complex solution would be to specify a "target width" for the columns in my table, e.g. `.25\textwidth` and then have the system optimize to produce a table that brings me as close to my specified whitespace score and table width as possible, while minimizing the number of hyphenated words... but I don't know if LaTeX can do this sort of dynamic optimization in several variables!  Here's one last image where I have gotten rid of the hyphenation entirely, by moving to `.27\textwidth` for columns.  This seems to be the most readable version yet.

[image]

Comment: Kindly add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: AFAIKT, the example is the picture -- this behavior should be familiar to anyone who uses LaTeX.   But if it helps anyone, here's a Gist https://gist.github.com/holtzermann17/5320882 with a table that includes LOTS of inter-word white space.

Comment: narrow columns always pose a nasty problem for attractive justification.  since the default hyphenation patterns produce `cor-rec-tions`, not to mention `han-dled or-phan-ing mech-a-nism non-re-spon-sive au-thors`, i'm wondering whether you're using them at all before trying `\nohyphens`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I don't think I'm doing anything to change the default hyphenation.  Here's the same table typeset using my actual preamble.  This is a NON-minimal example, since I'm doing a lot of things in the preamble... but again, I don't think there's anything there to change the hyphenation patterns.  https://gist.github.com/holtzermann17/5320983 (Should there be?  I.e. I think this is what I'm asking in the question above - is there anything to do to get LaTeX to hyphenate more aggressively?)

Comment: For narrow columns raggedright (see `ragged2e`) will usually be better; if you insist on justified text, use `microtype` and LuaTeX/pdfTeX.

Comment: How did you achieve the bad version on the right which you say is "the same text typeset by vanilla XeLaTeX"? I don't get that result from the code you linked to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When trying to typeset text in very narrow measures, it's sometimes best (least worst?!) to use the `\sloppy` directive, as is done in the following example.

It can also be helpful in such situations to set `\righthyphenmin2`. (For English-language texts, the default value of this parameter is `3`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=3.38in]{geometry} 
  % \textwidth = 8.5"-2*3.38" = 1.74"
\frenchspacing
\righthyphenmin2
\sloppy
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Quality control is handled with corrections and the ``orphaning'' mechanism in case 
of nonresponsive authors. Some articles are world-writeable, as in the wiki model.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried with the full example from the Gist, and it's not clear that `\sloppy` has _that much_ of an impact.  However, your point about `\righthyphenmin` is a good one.  I think what really matters here is `\lefthyphenmin`, in particular, `\lefthyphenmin=3` will solve the problem of the awkward "or-phaning".  (Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40324/pdflatex-and-hyphenation)  However, honestly this seems a bit more like a clever hack than a "smart" solution.  As in your example and my postscript, you can get arbitrarily good typesetting by changing the region width.

Comment: @JoeCorneli - If you're allowed to switch from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX (you're advisor might object, who knows!), you could make use of the `microtype` package to even out the "grayness value" of the textblock. I'd call that a pretty smart solution. :-) Incidentally, I couldn't run the example you posted to github as it makes use of a few fonts I don't have on my system.

Comment: latest version of `microtype` seems to work with XeLaTeX too, indeed, it's the walk-through example in `tlmgr help`.  Following the walkthrough didn't work for me, but `sudo /usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --all` did.  I've compiled the document with `\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}` and some of the other tweaks and things are indeed looking a bit better...

Comment: @JoeCorneli - the more I contemplate the matter, the less convinced I am that setting `\lefthyphenmin3` is a good solution. As you must know too, there are tons of English words that start with prefixes such as `in`, `re`, or `un`. For such words, it should be unobjectionable to hyphenate them after the prefix (in-quire, re-set, re-view, re-wind, un-clear, etc). Suppressing all hyphenation after two letters is bound to create more problems that it solves. If it's mostly about dealing with `orphaning`, you can always provide the instruction `\hyphenation{orphan-ing}` in the preamble, right?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why you are using `\nohyphens` I'd have thought you want more rather than less.
Using the linked table as you don't supply code for the example in the question I get this which isn't too bad, although could obviously be tweaked a bit more.

[image]

```
\documentclass[article,a4paper,12pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{hyphenat}

\setlrmarginsandblock{40mm}{20mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{20mm}{*}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\raisebox{3in}{\small
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{>{\hyphenpenalty0 }p{.25\textwidth}|}}
\hline
% \multicolumn{1}{p{.25\textwidth}}{\textbf{Relevance}}
\begin{center}(PM)
\end{center}

Ultimately relevance depends on peer review, and irrelevant content
may be deleted. Mechanisms to ensure that relevant content
\emph{will} be added could be improved. &
\begin{center}(WP)
\end{center}
People contribute articles about what
they're interested in; apart from this, rules like WP:WEIGHT come into
play.&
\begin{center}(DO)
\end{center}

Anyone can upload projects (for ``full projects'', one time approval
is needed), but getting changes into the core requires considerably
more vetting. \\
%\multicolumn{1}{p{.25\textwidth}}{\textbf{Quality}}
Quality control is handled with corrections and the ``orphaning'' mechanism
in case of nonresponsive authors. Some articles are world-writeable,
as in the wiki model. & Automated tools for spam and vandalism detection
combined with a system of editorial oversight, in which Jimmy Wales
has last say. & In addition to bug reports and feature requests handled
through the issue tracker, modules can make use of an automated patch
testing system.\\
%\multicolumn{1}{p{.25\textwidth}}{\textbf{Scalability}}
Peer review is distributed. Links are handled automatically. Caching
is deployed where relevant; in particular, interlinking features are
kept up to date. & The database and other infrastructure is massively
scaled. There are many bots that help with small tasks. & In theory,
anyone can join. Earl Miles, NYCCamp 2012 keynote: ``\emph{There are
no insiders, except Dries; there are no outsiders, only resumes.}''
\\
% \multicolumn{1}{p{.25\textwidth}}{\textbf{Consistency}}
Although automatic links and corrections can help with consistency,
mainly PM relies on standards for proof and expository quality.
&NPOV is the key rule, which works together with templates and other
process tools to maintain community standards about style and
content. & The project issue queues are the place to go when one
module's changes breaks another's. The core of the project has
considerable oversight in these
matters.\\
% \multicolumn{1}{p{.25\textwidth}}{\textbf{Motivation}}
People are solving some of their learning, exposition, and social
needs on the site by writing and reviewing articles and posting in the
forums.& As of 2006, over 50\% of the site had been written by less
than 1\% of the users; these days, paid editing is somewhat
notorious.& Miles continued: ``\emph{To build a resume, find someone
who needs help, and help them. Find something that needs doing, do
it.}'' \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\caption{As typeset ``out of the box''}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

If you allow a bit of flexibility on the right margin, and add microtype you get:

```
\usepackage{microtype}

...

\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{
   >{\hyphenpenalty0 \rightskip0pt plus .3em \emergencystretch2em}%
   p{.25\textwidth}|}}
```

[image]

Comment: my supervisor suggested to get rid of the hyphens because he didn't like the look of "or-phaning".  But for this example it also serves another purpose -- it helps us see whether or not hyphenation actually improves things.  It doesn't seem to help a lot, because there is still lots of whitespace.

Comment: @JoeCorneli - If your adviser can be placated if you write `\mbox{orphan}\-ing`, which suppresses the first of two possible hyphenation points in or-phan-ing, I'd go for it. More generally, to suppress all hyphenation instances after just two characters in a word, set `\lefthyphenmin3`.

Comment: @JoeCorneli since TeX only hyphenates to minimise the badness property of the paragraph, preventing hyphens will in almost all cases increase white space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - yes :-)  The point of producing the version without hyphenation was primarily exposition.  At the same time, my supervisor says that he always turns hyphenation off (in Word), so it was a good, neutral starting point...

Comment: @JoeCorneli Are you _sure_ you should be taking advice on hyphenation and line breaking from a Word user?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I think he had a valid typographical point, based on Exhibit B (which is the one he saw and what XeLaTeX produced by default with my input) and Exhibit D in the question (which is just massively better).

Comment: @JoeCorneli - There's a good reason why most Word users don't use hyphenation: It doesn't work all that well! It's certainly vastly inferior to TeX's hyphenation algorithm. Of course, no hyphenation algorithm will ever be perfect. In TeX, you always have the option to create hyphenation exceptions via the `\hyphenation` command (to be inserted in the preamble). Use `-` characters to indicate where hyphenation should be allowed in the words listed in the argument of the `\hyphenation` command.

Comment: @JoeCorneli you haven't supplied code for the examples in the question so they don't really show anything. But clearly if you change the line width you can optimise line breaks, however turning off hyphenation is unlikely to ever help, and certainly your examples don't show that they help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - your point has been taken with zero argument.  But since you're repeating the point, I can only repeat that that the reason I posted the text with no hyphenation (Exhibit A) is to see whether hyphenation actually improved things (Exhibit B).  Out of the box it is an improvement but not a solution.  Code for the examples is really not relevant since this is a ubiquitous issue for LaTeX with small columns - they get gappy!  I think the only "solution" would be a dynamic one, like in the PS of my post.  Regards! Joe

Comment: @JoeCorneli Questions should _always_ have complete document examples (if you expect people to test their answers). It is of course possible for latex to try multiple widths, but it really only makes sense for single isolated paragraphs like figure captions: in a table where all the widths need to add up to the text width, and different paragraphs in different entries want different values I can not really think of a good algorithm. (Implementing it in latex probably isn't the problem if there is an algorithm to be implemented)