# Custom hyphenation for different languages in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, languages, hyphenation, polyglossia

When I define custom hyphenation with `\hyphenation` in XeTeX, it seems to only work for the main body of the text, but not for the bits inside `\text<language>` (as in `\textgerman`) environments.

I know I can use `\-` but I would rather have a global solution.

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\begin{document}

\hyphenation{bb-bbb}

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbb

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \textgerman{bbbbb}

\end{document}
```

yields this:

[image: \hyphenation failing with \textgerman]

Comment: Maybe some of the solutions listed here also work with XeTeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37934/specifying-multiple-hyphenation-exception-lists-for-multi-lingual-documents

Comment: They surely work.

Comment: I might have done something wrong but I can't get either to work. They seem to depend on babel, while I want to use polyglossia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method with `hyphenrules` indeed doesn't work with Polyglossia (and it should be investigated why). You can do in another way:

```
\newcommand{\sethyphenation}[3][]{%
  \sbox0{\begin{otherlanguage}[#1]{#2}
    \hyphenation{#3}\end{otherlanguage}}}

\sethyphenation{german}{bb-bbbb}
\sethyphenation[variant=british]{english}{bbb-bbb}
```

The following document will show different hyphenations of `bbbbbb`

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\newcommand{\sethyphenation}[3][]{%
  \sbox0{\begin{otherlanguage}[#1]{#2}
    \hyphenation{#3}\end{otherlanguage}}}

\sethyphenation{german}{bb-bbbb}
\sethyphenation[variant=british]{english}{bbb-bbb}

\begin{document}

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbb

\textgerman{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  bbbbbb}

\end{document}
```

The syntax of `\sethyphenation` is

```
\sethyphenation[<options>]{<language>}{<list of words separated by spaces>}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot! Would you mind explaining the purpose of `\sbox0`, please? I can't see a different behaviour without it.

Comment: @KamilS. It's just to ensure that nothing is typeset. I'll ask Arthur Reutenauer to include this facility in Polyglossia.

Comment: That would be great. I'm a linguist and often mix many languages inside one text, so hyphenating them all manually was somewhat tedious. Thanks for the explanation.