# Hyphenation exceptions not loaded when using babel with multiple languages

Tags: languages, hyphenation, babel

When I use babel with more than one language loaded, my hyphenation exceptions are not used. Here is an example:

====== hy.tex =======

```
\hyphenation{para-dichloro-diphenyl-trichloro-ethane}
```

====== test.tex ======

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\selectlanguage{english}
\input{hy}

\begin{document}
paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane 
\end{document}
```

My hyphenation exception is not respected. If I remove `\selectlanguage`, however, the hyphenation exception works.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but please also upvote it (by clicking on the upward-pointing pen nib; upvoting has to be done separately from accepting an answer).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\hyphenation` commands refer to the current language, and `babel` switches to French at the start of your document body. Your example works as intended by switching to English and loading `hy.tex` after `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{hy.tex}
\hyphenation{para-dichloro-diphenyl-trichloro-ethane}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\input{hy}

\languagename

paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane paradichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, have a look at [Specifying multiple hyphenation exception lists for multi-lingual documents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37934/specifying-multiple-hyphenation-exception-lists-for-multi-lingual-documents).