# How to prevent words from running into the right margin?

Tags: line-breaking

I'm revising one of the final drafts of my thesis and on several pages there are words running into the right margin.

My question is **whether rewording the paragraph is the only way to get rid of this problem?** (I'd like to avoid using the command `\sloppy` because it screws up spacing between words.)

The related question [How can I make my text never go over the right margin by always hyphenating or breaking on word-boundaries?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9107/how-can-i-make-my-text-never-go-over-the-right-margin-by-always-hyphenating-or-b?lq=1) offers using `\sloppy` or rewording the paragraph as solutions. I'd like to know whether there are alternative solutions.

**Update** (January 31st 2016)**.** Using the [microtype](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/microtype/microtype.pdf) package did the job. Thanks to Henri Menke for suggesting this.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`microtype`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/microtype/microtype.pdf) package, which enables margin kerning and Hermann Zapf typography for enhanced line breaking.  Using this package the right way considerably lowers the number of hyphenations.

Comment: Using longer paragraphs may also help - it gives the line breaking algorithm more chances to find a good set of breaks.

Comment: you can hyphenate the long word by adding `\-`  you don't have to reword the paragraph or you can set \emergencystretch which does not change the spacing in good paragraphs or use microtype

Comment: Which language is your document in? Have you loaded `babel` with the appropriate language option(s) to help LaTeX find additional permissible hyphenation points? Are the words that are running into the right-hand margin not very common and hence maybe not known to TeX's hyphenation algorithm?

Comment: The document is written in English. In all cases either the em-dash (`---`) or the word attached to the em-dash (`word---`) is the thing that sticks out.

Comment: it would be easier to gave a specific answer if you showed an example document with (just) a paragraph of text showing the bad linebreaks

Comment: @HenriMenke, using the `microtype` package did the trick. Thank you all for prompt responses. (I guess you can reproduce the comment in the form of an answer so I can accept it and so others can spot the solution immediately.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The German LaTeX Wikibook contains a chapter about hyphenation -- here's the [link](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX-W%C3%B6rterbuch:_Silbentrennung).

### babel Package

First of all make sure that you use the [babel package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel). It loads hyphenation rules for the language you use.

### hyphsubst Package

If you write in German maybe the [hyphsubst package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyphsubst) is a good option.

### Manually Help LaTeX with the Hyphenation (Globally)

As stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121832/breaking-words-at-the-end-of-line) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27890/how-to-add-global-hyphenation-rules) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37934/specifying-multiple-hyphenation-exception-lists-for-multi-lingual-documents) for example you can add specific hyphenation rules in the preamble of your document:

```
% needs babel package
\hyphenation{cryp-to-graphy lalala-la lolo-lolo-lulu}
```

### Manually Help LaTeX with the Hyphenation (Locally)

I would recommend this as the last step when you finished your document. Then you can manually help LaTeX.

The command \overfullrule=2pt in the preamble will show you where LaTeX has a problem with hyphenation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% showframe to show the layout frames... :)
\usepackage[textwidth=50mm,showframe]{geometry}

% Show overfull boxes and lines (TeX primitive)
\overfullrule=2pt

\begin{document}

Lalalalalalala lalalalala lalalalala lalalalala

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a list of manual options:

- `\-` Hyphenation a word only here and nowhere else (all other hyphenation rules are not valid anymore).
- `"-` Hyphenation a word also here (the other hyphenation rules are still valid).
- `"=` This produces a dash. Hyphenation is allowed here and the other hyphenation rules are still valid. Normally if a word contains a dash the dash is the only place where a hyphenation can occur.
- `"~` This produces a dash where no hyphenation is allowed.
- `""` Here a hyphenation can occur but no automatic hyphenation dash will be produced by LaTeX.

> These commands work if you use `ngerman` option for `babel`. I do not
>   know how to make them work if you use other languages. **Can somebody help me on this?**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

% showframe to show the layout frames... :)
\usepackage[textwidth=50mm,showframe]{geometry}

% Show overfull boxes and lines (TeX primitive)
\overfullrule=2pt

\begin{document}

Lalalalalalala lalalalala lal"-lalala lalalalala

\end{document}
```

[image]

### microtype Package

> Stolen from the comments (@Henri Menke)!

The [microtype package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) also improves hyphenation. The following cite is taken from the package manual:

> **Micro-typography** is the art of enhancing the appearance and
>   readability of a document while exhibiting a minimum degree of visual
>   obtrusion. It **is concerned with what happens between or at the margins
>   of characters, words or lines.** Whereas the macro-typographical aspects
>   of a document (i.e., its layout) are clearly visible even to the
>   untrained eye, micro-typographical refinements should ideally not even
>   be recognisable. That is, you may think that a document looks
>   beautiful, but you might not be able to tell exactly why: good
>   micro-typographic practice tries to reduce all potential irritations
>   that might disturb a reader.